# Maven dependency works locally but fails in Github workflow

Tags: java, maven, github, github-actions

I have the following Maven dependency in my project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When I run the Maven build locally, the dependency downloads without problems. But when I run the build on Github, I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal on project my-project: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.test:my-project:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:jar:6.0.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:jar:6.0.0: Could not transfer artifact jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:pom:6.0.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/jakarta/servlet/jakarta.servlet-api/6.0.0/jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.pom: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org: Name or service not known -> [Help 1]
```

Other artefacts are downloading correctly. If I comment out the `servlet-api` dependency, the build passes.

Here is my workflow definition:

```
name: Java CI with Maven

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:

    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Set up JDK 17
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '17'
        distribution: 'temurin'

    - name: Cache local Maven repository
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: ~/.m2/repository
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-maven-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-maven-

    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn -B -P github deploy --file pom.xml
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There was an issue with the DNS resolution of that https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/jakarta/servlet/jakarta.servlet-api/6.0.0/jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.pom ... should be solved in the meantime... the question is also which Maven version do you use? See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/76060397/296328